# Display QRCODE in deveco studio 2.1

Tags: qr-code, deveco-studio

QRCODE is not displayed in Previewer even if I write the index.hml file as shown below in deveco studio 2.1.
Please tell me what to do. The API Version is 5.

index.hml

```
<div class="container">
    <text class="title">
        {{ $t('strings.hello') }} {{ title }}
    </text>
    <!--<button class="first" type="capsule" value="capsule button">
    </button>
    -->
    <qrcode value="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/" type="rect"
            style="color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;width: 300px;height: 300px;margin-bottom: 70px;"></qrcode>
</div>
```